# modify gnome's login/logout as user

Tags: debian, login, logout

My problem is following:
I want to modify my login/logout so if I login a program is started, if I log off, it is closed (which it isn’t usually). (To let you know what I’m talking about – it’s dropbox)

Firstly, I have no root-access to the machine I’m working on.
Secondly, I’m aware I can just start the dropbox each time I log on and make an alias for example for the logout, so if I logout an additional command is executed.

If there is no other way to do this ok, but what I would like to do is: modify the login and logout so, that if I login/logout as usual, the dropbox is started/stopped automatically.
Is there any other way to do this? My rights are restricted to my home-directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `bash` then commands in `~/.bash_login` are executed on log in and those in `~/.bash_logout` are executed on log out/off if these files exists.

If you happen to have a `~/.bash_profile` file that is readable, then that takes precedence over `~/.bash_login` and only that file is processed.

---

If you use `tcsh`, you can put the command to start dropbox in `~/.tcshrc` (or `~/.cshrc` if it exists, or `~/.login`) and for it to stop in `~/.logout`.

For `tcsh` the order in which the files on login are read can differ depending on how the shell is compiled (and which can be checked with `echo $version`)

Comment: sadly I dont have theses files in my home-directory.
Additionally - wouldn't this run just if I use the bash?
(tcsh is standard on the machine)

Comment: @groebsgr bash would need to be your login shell for them to work

Comment: @groebsgr I update the answer with info for `tcsh`

Comment: sadly there are none of these files in my homedirectory - i suppose on purpose by the administration. Nevertheless thank you very much so far!

Comment: @groebsgr you can create the files yourself, tcsh is unlikely to be compiled in a way that it ignores the files. Just make them and put an echo statement in to see if they work, then go from there.

Comment: with echo it seemed to work if I login with ssh over the shell, at the moment I can't test it with a usual login/logout.

So, thank you for your help, seems to work fine!

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal run

```
gnome-session-properties
```

Add dropbox to the list of start up applications.

Comment: I just tried it - the start seems to work fine with this, any ideas to stop the program at logout?  
A quick idea would be to make the command in the given properties so it stops dropbox if i logout, but i have to try this.